# Accesing nested JSON items with JQuery

Tags: jquery, json

I've been messing around with some aproaches, but haven't succeeded, I've succesfully parsed JSON data before using JQuery but now I just can't figure it out.

With this code,

```
$.each(data, function(headers, item){
    $.each(item, function(){
        console.log(item[i].date_c);
        i++;
    });
});
```

I can easily read all dates of a JSON object like this one:

[image]

But right now I don't know how to reach that date on a JSON object like this one: 
[image]

As you can see, there's a new level. Could you help me out?

Thanks in advance!

----------------EDIT
Thanks for being interested on helping me. The JSON is preety large, but you can take a look at it from here: http://vader.rice.edu/hed2/wormsr/data.php?kw=him-5

523 is an ID, every item has a different one; and for instance, there are 4 different dates corresponding to a single ID.

Comment: `$.each(item, function(){` ??? where is `items` ?? (s)

Comment: can you paste the json ? it would be nice to play with it

Comment: Could you provide a bit more information about the data structure of the new JSON. Is 523 a constant, does the date always sit in object 3, ... It is a bit hard to guess how to iterate without this information.

Comment: It's really hard to help you without seeing the the actual JSON. Where are the other `date_c` values located?

Comment: @user937471 paste the json (as text)

Comment: @user937471 this isthe first jsnon. where is the second ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/bqKHm/5/

You can use that json if you want to practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually most of the data inside your JSON Object is useful and formats are stable. If possible I would correct that, rather than writing a different script.

- Where did the item's element go?
- Why are your data 'date_c'-holding objects suddenly nested deeper?

As for syntax:

You are free to use the **.** Operator or the array access notation for objects (**[]**)

So you can write something like

```
//first structure
    data['items'][0]['date_c']
//second structure
    data[0][523][3]['date_c']
```

As you can see the data is simply deeper nested, so the solution is to add another `each` so you can have one more level to iterate through.

```
// 0 in our example
$.each(jsonData, function(index, firstLevel) {
    //523 in the example
    $.each(firstLevel, function(anotherindex, secondLevel) {
        // 3 in the example
        $.each(secondLevel, function(yetAnotherIndex, thirdLevel) {
            console.log(thridLevel['date_c']);
        });
    });
});
```

Please note that the paramters passed to the functions (*xxxLevel*) are the objects in your JSON format.

Comment: that only works if you know the number of levels. it's not very flexible.

Comment: If you exchange data, you most certainly do not need a flexible parser but a secure format.

Answer (score 1):

Are you just unsure where the date will appear? e.g. if the problem is simply to get all member objects in a construct (no matter how deeply nested) named "date_c" then use recursion.

This isn't tested but the basic logic should work: just iterate through the properties of objects, or the elements of arrays, looking for a property named 'date_c'. Try to recurse into any properties or array elements that could have children.

```
var findThem = function(data) {
    var result=null;
    // skip literals, they have no children
    if (typeof data === 'string' || typeof data === 'number') {
       return;
    }
    if (data && data.constructor && data.constructor.name ==='Array') {
        for(var i=data.length-1;i>=0;i--) {
            findThem(data[i]);
        }
    } else if (typeof data === 'object') {
        foreach (var prop in data) {
           if (data.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
               if (prop=='date_c') {
                   console.log(data[prop]);
               } else {
                   findThem(data[prop]);
               }
           }
       }
    }
}
```